# find m nearest neighbors in KD tree use java

Tags: java, data-structures, knn, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I want to implement KD tree in java for a data structure project but I have problem with special method that this project wants. In below you can see the format of method that I want.

```
float[][] findMNearest(float[] point, int m) {}
```

I implement find nearest neighbor method but for m nearest neighbor I have problem and I can't understand algorithm for solution.
[In this picture you can see my implementation for nearest neighbor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XthVK.png)

```
java
private void nearest(KDNode root, KDNode target, int index) {
        if (root == null)
            return;
        visited++;
        float d = root.distance(target);
        if (best == null || d < bestDistance) {
            bestDistance = d;
            best = root;
        }
        if (bestDistance == 0)
            return;
        float dx = root.getCoordinates()[index] - target.getCoordinates()[index];
        index = (index + 1) % k;
        nearest(dx > 0 ? root.getLeft() : root.getRight(), target, index);
        if (dx * dx >= bestDistance)
            return;
        nearest(dx > 0 ? root.getRight() : root.getLeft(), target, index);
    }
```

I don't want to use ready library, too.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

At the end my **friend** help me!
Full source of project for answer this question and other questions about kdtree and its methods at https://github.com/Iman9mo/KDTree

Comment: This first appeared to be follow up information. But on second thought it may be the answer? Please edit the answer to describe the linked code and how it solved the issue or edit the question to add more details.